# FluentValidation - How to customize the validation message in runtime

Tags: c#, validation, message, fluentvalidation

In this entity:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How can I customize the validation message in runtime using another property of entity or any other string obtained from the database?

The validation message for `RuleFor(foo => foo.Name)` would be:

```
var msg = "The foo with type '" + foo.Type + "' already exists in the database with name '" + nameInDataBase + "'!"
```

Comment: See https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/d.-Configuring-a-Validator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I had a complex scenario, the solution that solved my problem was found here: [Custom Validators](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom).

Here's the validator code:

```
public class FooValidator : AbstractValidator<Foo>
{
    public FooValidator()
    {
        Custom(foo =>
        {
            var repo = new Repository<Foo>();
            var otherFooFromDB = repo.GetByName(foo.Name);

            if (!otherFooFromDB.Equals(foo))
            {
                return new ValidationFailure("Id", "The foo with ID'" + otherFooFromDB.Id + "' has the same name of this new item '" + foo.Id + " - " + foo.Name + "'.!");
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

With this solution when validation is ok just return `null`.
But when there is a validation error return a instance of `ValidationFailure` and pass in her constructor the name of the validated property and the validation message.

Comment: I would make one change to the above and that is to inject your repo into the validator, otherwise you'll make testing it a pain.

Comment: Yes @YannickMeeus!! ...I use `Interface` for my repos to make possible testing... with mocks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a couple of custom validators, and define them as extension methods so you can chain them. Pass what you need to do the validation into the model. Then if you have foo.Type as a property of your model, you can display it in the message as shown below:

```
RuleFor(foo => foo.Name).FooTypeIsInvalidValidator().WithMessage("The foo with type: {0} is invalid!", foo => foo.Type);
```

or

```
RuleFor(foo => foo.Name).FooAlreadyExistsValidator().WithMessage("The foo with type: {0} already exists in the database with name", foo => foo.Type);
```

Comment: Thank you KN Coder (@kn-coder) but my scenario is more complex. I post the new answer.